# Laravel - Hide model properties in collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to hide the properties of a model, like table, connection, primaryKey, etc in a Laravel collection and keep only the attributes/columns of the table?

```
                        [table:protected] => product
                        [connection:protected] => mysql
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [keyType:protected] => int
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [withCount:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [exists] => 1
                        [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                ...
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                ...
                            )
                       ...
                    )
```

Comment: Call `->toArray()` on the collection if you want

Comment: Hide them from what? If you want them hidden from JSON responses, use `protected $hidden = ['foo'];` in your model to hide attributes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that because these are properties of an Eloquent model object and they will be ignored when you'll serialize the object or convert it to JSON or an array:

```
$model->toArray()
```

Comment: i tried this, but i lost the relationships of the model.. Is there a way to also keep the relationships?

Comment: @InoveCommerce loaded relations data will still be there, but it will be a multidimensional array and not a collection.